# How to correct page segmentation by Tesseract OCR using image processing?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, text-segmentation

For eg, the content beneath **Article Info** and **Abstract** are being considered as one single paragraph by Tesseract OCR. This is interfering with the selection of text later on.
After I fiddled around with some image processing steps (Gaussian Blur, Erosion followed by Dilation), I had managed to separate them somehow.

```
image = cv2.imread(file)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
gray = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
gray = cv2.dilate(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
cv2.imwrite( file.split('.')[0]+"_process.TIF", gray);
```

I do not understand how this altered segmentation, but it doesn't work right in every case. What could I do to get the segmentation right? Must I try any specific Image processing techniques?

Thank You

*Page segmentation viewed using PAGEViewer by PRImA*
[image: Page segmentation viewed using PAGEViewer by PRImA]

[image]

EDIT: Added orginal image

Comment: Please always post original image so that ppl can test their solutions. Also take a look at [page segmentation method](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method) for tesseract, playing with that might solve your problem straight away

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I tried all of those settings. They didn't really help.
I've added the orginal image now. Hope it helps